# You must pass java.security.auth.login.config in secure mode kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to run below kafka command(we are using kafka version 0.9) -

```
bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost --producer.config config\action-ssl.properties --topic topic_name
```

action-ssl.properties -

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="action" password="1111111";
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
ssl.truststore.location=D:\tool\kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0\config\kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=11111111
```

Exception-

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:181)
        at kafka.producer.NewShinyProducer.<init>(BaseProducer.scala:36)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:46)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass java.security.auth.login.config in secure mode.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:73)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:80)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:271)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass java.security.auth.login.config in secure mode.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.Login.login(Login.java:289)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.Login.<init>(Login.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:44)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:85)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:55)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Kafka 0.9.0.0. I would suggest upgrading to a recent version, but [according to this page](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/)

> The keystore configuration is needed in 0.9.0.0 due to a bug in Kafka, which has been fixed and will be included in 0.9.0.1.

> Finally, we pass the name of the JAAS file as a JVM parameter to the client JVM:

> ```
> -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_client_jaas.conf
> ```

Translating for windows...

```
set KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\path\to\kafka_client_jaas.conf"
kafka-console-producer.bat ...
```

Comment: If I upgrade version of kafka, it will not need to pass jaas file as JVM parameter and issue will resolve ?

Comment: You still need to pass it. It cannot magically know what the JAAS configs are